# Recursive SQL to get data

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchy

I have two tables
PS_ITEM and PS_ITEM_XREF

Structure of PS_ITEM

```
COMMON_ID   ITEM_NBR        SEQ   EMPLID     ACCOUNT_NBR  CLASS_NBR
00000000200 000000000000002 1   00000000200 TUT001       10146
00000000200 000000000000002 2   00000000200 TUT001       10146
00000000200 000000000000002 3   00000000200 TUT001       10146
00000000200 000000000000006 1   00000000200 VAT001       10146
00000000200 000000000000008 1   00000000200 TUT001       10146
00000000200 000000000000003 1   00000000200 VAT001       
00000000200 000000000000004 1   00000000200 VAT001       
00000000200 000000000000009 1   00000000200 TUT001       10143
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Structure of PS_ITEM_XREF

```
   COMMON_ID    ITEM_NBR_CHARGE  ITEM_NBR_PAYMENT AMOUNT
   00000000200  000000000000003  000000000000006  2100
   00000000200  000000000000010  000000000000009  1000
```

I would like to select values from PS_ITEM where class_nbr = 10146 ALONG WITH all the ROWS
where PS_ITEM.ITEM_NBR=PS_ITEM_XREF.ITEM_NBR_CHARGE for all the rows where PS_ITEM_XREF.ITEM_NBR_PAYMENT in PS_ITEM where class_nbr = 10146

So my result would be

```
    COMMON_ID   TEM_NBR        SEQ   EMPLID     ACCOUNT_NBR  CLASS_NBR
    00000000200 000000000000002 1   00000000200 TUT001       10146
    00000000200 000000000000002 2   00000000200 TUT001       10146
    00000000200 000000000000002 3   00000000200 TUT001       10146
    00000000200 000000000000006 1   00000000200 VAT001       10146
    00000000200 000000000000008 1   00000000200 TUT001       10146
    00000000200 000000000000003 1   00000000200 VAT001
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   PS_ITEM 
WHERE  ( CLASS_NBR='10146' 
         OR 
         ITEM_NBR IN 
         ( SELECT  ITEM_NBR_CHARGE 
           FROM    PS_ITEM_XREF
           WHERE    ITEM_NBR_PAYMENT IN (SELECT ITEM_NBR FROM PS_ITEM WHERE CLASS_NBR='10146')))
```

Comment: It gives me all the rows which exists in PS_ITEM_XREF however it should only give me the row with ITEM_NBR = 000000000000003

Comment: @RohitPrasad . . . The results look correct to me:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc34c8490bf66ac8956ea069ab506cc4.